# Kotlin: Show/hide ImageView in

Tags: android, kotlin

Within a multiple choice quiz, I want an ImageView to show for some questions and be hidden for others. When I omit `android:src` in XML, the ImageView is hidden for all questions. When I set `android:src`, the ImageView shows for all questions.

How can I set the image visibility dynamically?

XML

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/image_1"/>
```

Data class

```
data class Questions(
    val id: Int, val image: Int?, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String, val option3: String, val option4: String, val correctAnswer: Int)
```

Question function

```
object ConstantsAnalysis {
        const val TOTAL_CORRECT: String = "total_correct"
        const val TOTAL_OPP: String = "total_opp"
        fun getQuestions(): ArrayList<Questions> {
            val questionList = ArrayList<Questions>()

            val q1 = Questions (1, image_1,"Question 1:","A","B","C","D", 3)

            val q2 = Questions (2, null,"Question 2:","A","B","C","D", 2)

            val q3 = Questions (3, image_2,"Question 3:","A","B","C","D", 1)

            questionList.addAll(listOf(q1, q2, q3))
            questionList.shuffle()
            return questionList
        }
    }
```

Comment: by making use of the visibility in xml and then changing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function used to set my question, calling `image_view.isVisible = question.image != null` did the trick.